# ASP.NET MVC Code-First Building Empty Migrations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am assuming there is something I am missing but when I generate migrations in a project, they keep showing empty Up and Down methods.  Even in a brand new project. Here are my steps.

Launch Visual Studio 2019.  Create a new ASP.NET Web Application (.net framework) C# project (4.7.2).  Choose MVC and under authentication select Individual User Accounts.  Click create to create the project.

Next I Enable Migrations.

```
Enable-Migrations
```

Next I add my first migration.

```
Add-Migration First
```

A first migration is successfully added with all the identity information for individual user accounts. All is good.

I update the database to apply the migration.  All is still good.

```
Update-Database
```

Now, I add a new class to the Models folder called SchoolContext.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication6.Models
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }    
        public SchoolContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I now go back to the Package Manager Console to create another migration.  I attempt to create a new migration.

```
Add-Migration Second
```

But this time, the class is empty.  it does not create my new table.

```
namespace WebApplication6.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    
    public partial class Second : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {

        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  Why doesn't it want to generate a migration with my new table?

As requested, this is what my ApplicationDbContext looks like in my IdentityModel.cs class generated by Visual Studio.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/code-first-approach-with-asp-net-mvc-framework/  look at this simple tutorial

Comment: That example works but i can't seem to get it to work when the identitymodel has been autogenerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first migration created users tables, then I assume that it used `IdentityDbContext`. Then, you need to inherit your `SchoolContext` not from `DbContext`, but from `IdentityDbContext`.

UPDATE: based on the latest update of the question, it is clear that application already has one database context, which is `ApplicationDbContext`. So usually it is enough to keep all `DbSet<>` in one database context. No need to create new context.

Comment: I tried to inherit `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` but that didn't work.  But i did find adding this `public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }` directly to the ApplicationDbContext method in IdentityModel.cs worked.  then the migration generated correctly.  Not sure if i understand why.

Comment: Could you post then your 'ApplicationDbContext' class here?

Comment: I will add it to my original post

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the dbset property.

Put it as following example so that migrations can detect the new class/table.
After adding the dbset property, add new migration to see the new class written.

If you already have a migration pending then write -force for the code to see new changes and update migration

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection") {
     }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
     {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
     }

    public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
   }
```

Note that there are 2 dbcontexts which is not of clear use, use only ApplicationDBContext and remove the other.